# MBR protective to MBR hybrid OSX

Tags: windows-7, macos, mbr, gpt, gdisk

Right to the point

I wanted to install W10, but it said that it doesn't like my gpt partition. So, with the help of gdisk, I followed this tutorial [MBR hybrid to MBR protective](https://superuser.com/questions/508026/windows-detects-gpt-disk-as-mbr-in-efi-boot)

Buuuuut it turns out that f** W10, and I want W7, so I have to go back to MBR hybrid... Could you please guys help me, PLEASE??? Can you tell me (like the well explained tutorial I linked) how to do it??? Thanks in advance.
This is how I am right now:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yEKE.png)

Thank u all !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Rod Smith... I actually found the solution few hours later. Here is how I did it and it worked like a charm

The commands (n, p, etc...) below were taken from gdisk -help

```
1. sudo gdisk /dev/disk0
2. r
3. p
4. h
5. Select the partition to "hybridize"
6. y
7. 07 -> So we can install Windows
8. y
9. n [Unused partitions…]
10. o
11. w
```

I STRONGLY ADVICE you read throughout the tutorial: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html

Hope I can help somebody :)

Answer (score 0):

A single GPT disk can have either a legal protective MBR or the ugly hack that is a hybrid MBR, but not both. If Windows 7 is already installed in BIOS mode, which requires a hybrid MBR, then you have several choices:

- Don't install Windows 10. Perhaps you could run it in VirtualBox, VMware, or some other virtualization environment.
- Install Windows 10 in EFI mode to a second disk that uses GPT with a conventional protective MBR.
- Move Windows 7 from its current location to a second disk that uses a pure MBR setup. You can then install Windows 10 to your current disk, giving it a protective MBR. This may be the cleanest solution if you really need to boot both versions of Windows directly, but it will also involve the most work, since you must move your working Windows 7 installation to a second disk.
- Install Windows 10 in BIOS mode. This will require changes in the way you boot the installer. It will also require changes to your hybrid MBR to support putting (at least) two NTFS partitions in the hybrid MBR. Although such a configuration may not be trail-blazing, it will be close enough that you'll have a hard time tracking down help. I recommend asking on a Mac forum.
- Convert your one disk from GPT to pure MBR and install both versions of Windows in BIOS mode. This approach is *theoretically* workable, but very few Mac users follow it, so you may run into unexpected problems, particularly surrounding booting OS X. (OS X is almost always installed on a GPT disk, so getting it booting from MBR will be another close-to-trail-blazing thing.)

Overall, the solutions involving virtualization or two disks are the safest ones. I don't recommend you try the others; I mention them just to be complete.