# Shared partition between OSX and Windows 10 (using Bootcamp) Disappeared?

Tags: macos, windows-10, partitioning, dropbox, boot-camp

Longtime windows user giving OSX a go. My idea was to install Windows via BootCamp and have a shared partition that holds my Dropbox folder (to avoid having dropbox take twice the room on my SSD), music and some other media.

It wasn't a breeze to setup (this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/508026/windows-detects-gpt-disk-as-mbr-in-efi-boot) helped me allot after my bootcamp disappeared when adding the shared partition in disk utility) but eventually I got it going. Today however after setting up Dropbox on Windows (not sure if coincidental) the shared partition disappeared and is not showing in either OS (I mean in Finder/File Explorer).

The Shared partition is the 250GB one and was formatted as ExFAT.

This is what Disk Utility is showing:
[image: Disk Utility]
[image: Partitions]

This is the output I am getting from GDisk:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/disk0: 977105060 sectors, 465.9 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): E17AF55E-F8EF-4DE3-9767-F7CCC3C37CDC
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 977105026
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 262281 sectors (128.1 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640       292336615   139.2 GiB   AF05  Untitled
   3       292336616       293606151   619.9 MiB   AB00  Recovery HD
   4       293606152       781438975   232.6 GiB   0700  Windows_NTFS_Untitl...
   5       781701120       977104895   93.2 GiB    0700  BOOTCAMP
```

Comment: How can one set this up? (Either using NTFS or exFAT.) I've been searching for ages and no clear guides are coming up. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you post it as a separate question. It's not very hard to set up... You start by setting up bootcamp, install Windows etc. Then you shrink your OSX partition to make room for a third (shared) partition in DIsk Utility. The hardest choice you will have is which file system to format the shared partition as - as you can see in this question ExFAT (which is native to both OSes) isn't a good choice because it isn't journaled. so the better option is to go either HFS or NTFS and use third party tools to make it read/write on the other OS.

Good luck!

Comment: Some useful links:
https://www.howtogeek.com/189250/how-to-share-files-between-mac-os-x-and-windows-with-boot-camp/
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282062/can-i-have-windows-share-disk-space-with-macos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after much research I managed to resolve the issue. Looks like ExFAT is susceptible to corruption, but you can actually repair it in terminal. In hindsight it looks like a better solution would have been to format the shared drive as NTFS and use [Paragon NTFS](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) to read/write to the share in OSX.

#### Solution

If you encounter a similar issue with ExFAT under OSX, the steps to solve it are as follows:

1. Find out your partition identifier in Terminal by running the command

   `diskutil list`
2. run the following command to repair the disk (replace `disk0s4` with whatever your partition name is according to step 1)

   `sudo fsck_exfat -d disk0s4`

The disk will be scanned and repaired (you will be prompted whether you want to repair).

#### Sources:

[exFAT partition got corrupted, but was easily fixed. How did this happen?](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/exfat-partition-got-corrupted-but-was-easily-fixed-how-did-this-happen.1771764/)

[Repairing a Corrupted Mac OSX ExFAT Partition](https://craigsmith.id.au/2014/07/06/repairing-a-corrupted-mac-osx-exfat-partition/)

[List All Mounted Drives and their Partitions from the Terminal](http://osxdaily.com/2009/12/01/list-all-mounted-drives-and-their-partitions-from-the-terminal/)

[Access SAME dropbox folder on MacOS and Windows in BOTH Parallels AND BootCamp?](https://forum.parallels.com/threads/access-same-dropbox-folder-on-macos-and-windows-in-both-parallels-and-bootcamp.110203/)