# Bootcamp reboot into Mac OS X & reboot into Windows toggles do not work

Tags: boot, mac, partitioning, mbr

I have a Mac Pro 5,1 and for some reason I am unable to reboot into Windows 10 when I have it selected in the System Preferences pane as the startup disk. When I do that I get a flashing cursor or I get a message on the screen saying there is no bootable media or a message like that. And when I select "reboot into OS X" or select OS X as the startup disk in Windows it does nothing and boots to windows. The only way for me to switch is to use the option key. Anybody have any ideas on how I can fix this? I already updated the boot camp utility in windows to 6.1 but it didn't work. I initially had problems in the start where Windows detects GPT disk as MBR in EFI boot so I had to follow [this](https://superuser.com/questions/508026/windows-detects-gpt-disk-as-mbr-in-efi-boot) guide to fix that but I'm not sure if that affected my install.

Comment: What macOS is on the Mac? How did you get Win10 onto it in the first place? As it's not qualified for Win10, usually people upgrade from 7, which leaves it on a protected MBR rather than newer EFI boot. I really don't know if those old Mac Pros can use the modern EFI method. Your issue was definitely prevalent in early days of Win10, but the BCA update was the usual fix. I found this but idk how much it helps - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334944/mac-pro-5-1-windows-10-boot-problems

Comment: @Tetsujin I used the guide at (https://superuser.com/questions/508026/windows-detects-gpt-disk-as-mbr-in-efi-boot) to get it to work. Before the installer refused to install to disk but after that it worked. The only thing that doesn't work is the OS switching within the OS unless I use the option key at startup.

Comment: I'm completely lost on that method tbh. I've only ever done it in BCA. You don't have anything like Paragon NTFS running, do you? That will prevent BC from switching over correctly.